# App screen is taking time to return to its original position when keyboard slides down in Android

Tags: android

When I click on an edit text to enter some value in it, the keyboard is appearing on the screen and the screen is getting resized accordingly but the app screen is not returning to its original position as soon as the keyboard goes down, it is taking some time to return.

That's why some portion of the screen is being cut for some time.

I have already tried:

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged|adjustResize"
```